# How to make a loaded bar by SoundCloud API

Tags: css, api, audio, soundcloud, soundmanager2

I am making a custom player by SoundCloud API. I made a bar that shows the part of the song that is playing. But I would like to have another bar that shows the streamed/loaded part of the song. So the streamed bar is always further than the bar that is playing currently.
[image]

Here is my code that shows the seek bar:

```
function playIt() {
    SC.stream("/tracks/147310720", function (sound) {
        sound.play({
            whileplaying: function () {
                $(".seekLoad").css('width', ((sound.position / sound.duration) * 100) + '%');
            },
        });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danials/wBZyX/3/)

Any idea how to make it?

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming you want both a loading and playing bar, start with positioning 2, 100% wide div's on top of where you want the bar to be displayed.

Then use the "whileloading" and the "whileplaying" functions from the soundmanager api to update the width of those bars in percents. Like so:

```
whileloading: function() {
    $(".loadBar").css('width', ((this.bytesLoaded/this.bytesTotal) * 100) + '%');
},
```

and obviously exactly the same for the playing bar.

If you don't want a playing bar but just a dot, just calculate the percentage is away from the left side of the loadingbar.

```
whileplaying: function() {
    $(".dot").css('left', ((this.bytesLoaded/this.bytesTotal) * 100) + '%');
},
```

You need some css styling obviously, and some knowledge regarding absolute, relative and fixed positioning, but you shouldn't be working on this if you wouldn't know that... (right?)